# How to allow directory listing with htacess, but disable browser caching?

Tags: javascript, apache, caching

I have an XML directory on an Apache 2.2.14 server (Ubuntu 10.04). I simply want to enable people to download files from this directory by providing a link to it from my PHP application.

The problem is that browsers cache their initial file list and don't update to show new files unless F5 is pressed. This directory gets a lot of new files and while it doesn't need real-time updates, I would appreciate not having to write a note in the footer reminding customers they need to F5 to see the file they just uploaded.

Bonus question: Could I just put `Options -Indexes` in httpd.conf to avoid creating a root .htaccess file?

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerName localhost
FileETag none
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
ExpiresByType text/html A86400
```

**root .htaccess file:**

```
Options -Indexes
```

**XML directory .htaccess file**

```
Options +Indexes
IndexIgnore .. *.shtml
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble XHTML HTMLTable SuppressDescription Charset=UTF-8 NameWidth=*
HeaderName HEADER.shtml
ReadmeName README.shtml
AddType text/xml .xml
```

**HEADER.shtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
  </head>
  <body>
```

**README.shtml**

```
  </body>
</html>
```

Might be worth pointing out that this is how the link is open via javascript:

```
var newWin = window.open(url,name,'height=800,width=600,menubar=no,titlebar=0,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,screenX=100,screenY=100,dependent=no');
newWin.focus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `ExpiresActive Off` to the **XML directory .htaccess file** and the directory list is always fresh now.